# Flutter: FutureBuilder issue

Tags: flutter

Generated list is sending null future

```
  class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  AppStateViewModal appStateViewModal = AppStateViewModal();

  late Future<List<PackageDataModal>> packageList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    packageList = _getPackageList();
  }

  Future<List<PackageDataModal>> _getPackageList() async {
    return await appStateViewModal.getPackages();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: packageList,
      builder: (context,
              AsyncSnapshot<List<PackageDataModal>> packageSnapshot) =>
          packageSnapshot.hasData
              ? GridView.builder(
                  itemCount: packageSnapshot.data!.length,
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 1),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => CardView(
                    packageData: PackageDataModal(
                        title: packageSnapshot.data![index].title,
                        description: packageSnapshot.data![index].description,
                        packageId: packageSnapshot.data![index].packageId),
                    imageList: const <ImageDataModal>[
                      // Generate a "Imagelist" for every "packageId"
                      // packageId is "$index"
                      // I want to return "List<ImageDataModal>""
                      // But I am getting "Future<List<ImageDataModal>>""
                      // to fix it, i just need to "await" but build cant do "Async"
                      // What i am doing wrong ?
                      // ApiUrl is like /api/packages
                      // and after this
                      // ApiUrl is like /api/packages/$index/images as List
                      // BackEnd Services is sending back the data to widget
                      // I have seen with doing print statments
                      // First FutureBuilder is running fine but when it comes to next
                      // Data is not showing.
                      // Dummy ImageDataModal is working and shwoing the expected behaviour
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              : const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
    );
  }
}
```

I was trying to Pass the Future to next Widget and then trying to use FutureBuilder but no success. Data is not reaching there.

```
class CardView extends StatefulWidget {
  const CardView({Key? key, required this.imageList, required this.packageData})
      : super(key: key);

  final PackageDataModal packageData;
  final Future<List<ImageDataModal>> imageList;

  @override
  State<CardView> createState() => _CardViewState();
}

class _CardViewState extends State<CardView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<ImageDataModal>>(
        future: widget.imageList,
        builder: (context, imageSnapshot) => Card(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  CarouselSlider.builder(
                    itemCount: imageSnapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, imageIndex, pageIndex) =>
                        CachedNetworkImage(
                      imageUrl: imageSnapshot.data![imageIndex].image,
                      placeholder: (context, text) => const Placeholder(),
                    ),
                    options:
                        CarouselOptions(aspectRatio: 16 / 9, autoPlay: true),
                  ),
                  Text(widget.packageData.title),
                  const SizedBox(height: 2),
                  Text(widget.packageData.description),
                ],
              ),
            ));
  }
}
```

[image]

I checked the Service which is calling the api to fetch the data is working fine and i checked it that it is reaching the card_view_widget.dart file properly

Comment: Why don't you make the cardview accept future and during the display of the images in cardview you display it from a FutureBuilder otherwise you may be required to attach your CardView code or your imageList usage code.

Comment: The following _CastError was thrown building
FutureBuilder<List<ImageDataModal>>(dirty,
state:
_FutureBuilderState<List<ImageDataModal>>#1c
f18):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  FutureBuilder<List<ImageDataModal>>
  FutureBuilder:file:///Users/dishankjindal/
  Documents/projectro/heaven_riders_india/li
  b/view/page/home/widgets/card_view_widget.
  dart:22:12

Comment: That is a null safety error - meaning that you are checking for null value on already null value, can you please show your usage code for the card_view_widget

Comment: just updated the post please check!!

Comment: https://github.com/dishankjj/heaven_riders_india

Comment: Data is not reaching to the card view widget. i don't know if my approach is wrong or i did some blunder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First correct your card_view_widget to be null aware(Handle null list)

```dart
class CardView extends StatefulWidget {
  const CardView({Key? key, this.imageList, required this.packageData})
      : super(key: key);

  final PackageDataModal packageData;
  final Future<List<ImageDataModal>>? imageList;

  @override
  State<CardView> createState() => _CardViewState();
}

class _CardViewState extends State<CardView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<ImageDataModal>>(
      future: widget.imageList,
      builder: (context, imageSnapshot) {
        if (!imageSnapshot.hasData &&
            imageSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }

        if (!imageSnapshot.hasData) {
          return Text(
            'No image found',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
          );
        }

        return Card(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              CarouselSlider.builder(
                itemCount: imageSnapshot.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, imageIndex, pageIndex) =>
                    CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: imageSnapshot.data![imageIndex].image,
                  placeholder: (context, text) => const Placeholder(),
                ),
                options: CarouselOptions(aspectRatio: 16 / 9, autoPlay: true),
              ),
              Text(widget.packageData.title),
              const SizedBox(height: 2),
              Text(widget.packageData.description),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

let me know of other errors

Comment: i edited but it has no data. no image found!! i am going to share the github link please check

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. My data model, which is `Model.fromjson`, was mapping the wrong key. I was getting the HTTP response properly, but it was sending the null data to the `Future<List>`.

It was `String itemId`, but I changed it previously and forgot to do the fix to `String packageId` as I was getting the JSON string.